# jquery pinnable alert messages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to have a pinnable message for errors and success message display.
By default it disappears within seconds but if pinned, it remains on the page. 
The message should be displayed floating above the html content but the html content must be accessible. 
I have remembered using similar message somewhere a year ago, but could not find it to referenced it. 
Is there any plugin for that, or any reference to start working on?

Comment: i was able to use that plugin with normal javascript alert method.

Comment: What you have already ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to gral.pancho.villa's capable answer above, here is another jQuery plugin that could be helpful.

The operative search term for this one is "Growl", which is a notification system used on Mac and Linux (and now Windows) OS.

http://www.erichynds.com/blog/a-jquery-ui-growl-ubuntu-notification-widget

Other references of debatable interest:

[GROWL - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growl_(software))
[Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/)
[Growl for OSX](http://growl.info/)
[SU Ques](https://superuser.com/questions/235417/whats-the-linux-equivalent-of-os-xs-growl)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for your trouble.

Comment: It was no trouble, I was glad to help. Keep asking questions!

Answer (score 1):

What about [Sticky Notes](http://www.jquery-sticky-notes.com/)? It is a jquery plug-in, and a base that you can start with.
You know, it was not hard to find. I guess that is why the Question got a couple of downvotes. Anyhow, the Key Words for this search were: "Sticky", "Note".

Comment: Several times in the past I could have found some information for myself, *if I had only known the appropriate words for a search.* As it was, I had no idea what to search for... until some good soul, such as yourself, clued me in. Well done. +1

Comment: I was looking to change my ui for displaying message. I have found Sticky Notes but it was not what I was looking for. It is a good replacement for what I am looking for. Thank you for your suggestion. My question is little stupid though.